# Use ESPER timestamp in EPL Online Test

Tags: sql, esper, epl, nesper

I have a simple question, for which I cannot find any ansers on stackoverflow or the ESPERTECH website. My plan is to write an ESPER CEP engine to check values in a live system. To check if the rules are correct even after editing them, 
I have some already recorded test cases in a database for which the rules should definatly fire. all sensor values are in a table that looks like that:

```
+---------------+-----------------+--------------+-------------+-----------------+----+
| timestamp     | temp_livingroom | temp_bedroom | temp_garden | humidity_garden | id |
+---------------+-----------------+--------------+-------------+-----------------+----+
| 1521044250000 | 15              | 15           | 10          | 50              | 1  |
+---------------+-----------------+--------------+-------------+-----------------+----+
| 1521044260000 | 20              | 15           | 15          | 30              | 2  |
+---------------+-----------------+--------------+-------------+-----------------+----+
| 1521044270000 | 25              | 20           | 17.5        | 25              | 3  |
+---------------+-----------------+--------------+-------------+-----------------+----+
```

is it possible if I get the event data in this format:

```
SensorVal={id=1, timestamp =1521044250000, temp_livingroom = 15,  temp_bedroom = 15, temp_garden = 10, humidity_garden = 50 }
SensorVal={id=1, timestamp =1521044260000, temp_livingroom = 20,  temp_bedroom = 15, temp_garden = 15, humidity_garden = 30 }
```

to use it as an inputstream in any way in the EPL Online Tryout so that I could use it straight away and use the timestamp as "esper-time"?
I'd like to avoid a t.plus(10 seconds) as I would have to add it manually.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to automate tests using Junit. You could fashion automated tests like Esper does, and Espers tests can be found at [Esper test suite](https://github.com/espertechinc/esper/tree/master/esper-regression/src/test/java/com/espertech/esper/regression)

Converting database rows into some instructions for EPL-Online can be done by custom code.

Comment: ok, thank you! can Esper handle json instead native? if yes, where can I find more information

Comment: The thing is I will have let's say 70 different scenarios for one rule which should be tested sometimes. then on the other side I will have data of a whole day at the end of the day and i want to run a batch processing when the data is available (around midnight). The data is in a database and can be exported as in the question or in JSON objects

Comment: Esper with Json is by using Avro with Esper-Avro. Avro brings the Json schema. Json alone as its without schema is not great to work with. Without avro, reading Json into objects or maps is recommended.